# How to FIND my comment on Youtube?

Tags: youtube

I need to find my comment on youtube.

"Find" in computerized sense: specify some criteria and pinpoint the comment.

Scrolling millions of pages by hand doesn't mean "find".

So, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

On the web interface:

1. Click your user icon in the top right.
2. Select *Your Data in YouTube* (it's below *Settings*).
3. Under the *Your YouTube Dashboard* section click *More* to expand. (You can view [but not search] your comments here.)
4. Click *Download YouTube Data* then follow the Google Takeout instructions, but:
5. Click the *All YouTube Data Included* button and deselect everything except *my-comments* (or at least deselect videos and music).

Once the download is ready (you'll receive an email):

6. Download and open the ZIP file.
7. In one of the folders there's a file *my-comments.html*, extract it or open it in a web browser.
8. Use the web browser's "find on page" feature to search for specific comments.

https://takeout.google.com/takeout/custom/youtube will take you directly to step 4.

https://takeout.google.com/takeout/downloads will show you Takeout downloads if you need to access it not through the email.

https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history will take you straight to your comment history; if your comment is recent you might be able to find it quickly on this page instead of having to download and search the entire history.

Comment: I was afraid of that :)

Comment: @Dims https://www.youtube.com/feed/history/comment_history will take you straight to your comment history; if your comment is recent you might be able to find it quickly on this page instead of having to download and search the entire history. If you're trying to automate it you could probably write a user script to continue retrieving (it loads as needed on scroll) and searching results on this page but ymmv.

Comment: I know people have written tools that interface with browse_ajax in various ways (e.g. https://github.com/nlitsme/youtube_tool) so something should be possible. I'd be surprised if it wasn't out there already.